# Guessing Game python binary search

Tags: python

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code here. I am trying to have the user think of a number between 1 and 100 and then this program will be able to guess it. The program adds the high and low numbers of the range and divides by two and uses that as the guess. The user enters a 1 if the number the program guess is higher than their number, -1 if it is lower, and 0 if the guess is correct. After at most 7 guesses the number guessed should be right. When I run my code it constantly prints out the guess as 50 and never changes. It seems to never be running through the if statements. It should be running through the program and finding a new guess.

```
def main():
    import random
    print("Guessing Game")
    print("")
    print("Think of a number 1 and 100 inclusive.\nAnd I will guess what it is in 7 tries or less.")
    print("")
    ready = input("Are you ready? (y/n): ")
    print("")
    if ready != "y" and ready != "n":
        ready = input("Are you ready? (y/n): ")
    if ready == "n":
        print("Bye")
    if ready == "y":
        lo = 0
        hi = 100
        guess_high = 1
        guess_same = 0
        guess_low = -1  
        a = random.randint(1,100)
        num_list = []
        for i in range(1,100):
            num_list.append(i)
        while (lo <= hi):
            guess_count = 0
            for guess_count in range(1,8):
                guess_count += 1
                guess = (lo + hi) // 2
                print("Guess",guess_count," : The number you thought was",guess)
                user_response = input("Enter 1 if my guess was high, -1 if low, and 0 if correct: ")
                if (user_response == 1):
                    hi = guess - 1
                    guess_count += 1
                    guess = (lo + hi) // 2
                elif (user_response == -1):
                    lo = guess + 1
                    guess_count += 1
                    guess = (lo + hi) // 2
                elif (user_response == 0):
                    print("Thank you for playing the Guessing Game.")
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is in lines 29, 30, 34, 38: `input()` returns a string, but you are testing against an int. `"1"` is not equal to `1`!

Some other problems:

- line 2: `import random` should not be in `main()`
- lines 7-10: getting a yes/no response for `ready` should be done in a `while` loop or (better) in its own function - repeat until a valid response is gotten
- lines 9, 11, 13: you need to learn about `else` and `elif`
- line 14: should be `lo = 1`
- line 19: what is `a` for? You never use it.
- lines 20-22: you do *not* need to keep a list of every possible number, just the lowest and highest possible values, which you already have (`lo` and `hi`), and if you *did* you could do `num_list = list(range(1, 100))`
- lines 25, 26, 32, 36: incrementing `guess_count` is useless and unnecessary because it is reset each time you re-enter the `for` loop

Here is a cleaned-up version:

```
# assumes Python 3
def get_yn(prompt, yes_values={"y", "yes"}, no_values={"n", "no"}):
    """
    Prompt for a yes or no response;
    return True for yes or False for no
    """
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).strip().lower()
        if response in yes_values:
            return True
        elif response in no_values:
            return False

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    """
    Prompt for a number,
    return as int
    """
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= value) and (hi is None or value <= hi):
                return Value
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_one_of(prompt, values):
    """
    Prompt for a response in values,
    return response string
    """
    while True:
        value = input(prompt).strip().lower()
        if value in values:
            return value

def main():
    print(
        "Guessing Game\n"
        "\n"
        "Think of a number in [1..100],\n"
        "and I will try to guess it in no more than 7 tries.\n"
    )

    if get_yn("Are you ready? (y/n): "):
        lo, hi = 1, 100
        got_it = False
        for attempt in range(1, 8):
            guess = (lo + hi) // 2
            print("I guess {}!".format(guess))
            res = get_one_of("Was this [L]ow, [H]igh, or [C]orrect? ", {"l", "h", "c"})            
            if res == "l":
                lo = guess + 1
            elif res == "h":
                hi = guess - 1
            else:  # correct!
                got_it = True
                break
            if lo > hi:
                break
        if got_it:
            print("Ha! Got it in {} guesses!".format(attempt))
        else:
            print("Something smells in the state of Denmark...")
    else:
        print("Bye!")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm required to have the string part on line 29 and then the user either enters a 1,-1, or 0

Comment: @user3500257: then test `if (user_response == "1"):` or it won't work!