# How to implement a numeric guessing game with loops in Python

Tags: python

So I'm creating this game where the computer guesses a number, and based on the reply, it splits and re-selects a number. I've had little problems so far, but now I'm quite stuck on the loop. I know what I have to do, I just can't figure out how to do it properly, and have it function.

```
lowest = int(input( "What is the lowest number you will think of?: "))
highest = int(input( "What is the highest number you will think of?: "))
print("So you're thinking of a number between",lowest,"and",highest)
x=[]
for number in range(lowest,highest):
    x.append(number)
middleIndex = (len(x))//2                 
print ("is it "+str(x[middleIndex])+"?")      
answer = input("")
if answer == "lower":
        x = (x[:len(x)//2])
else:
        x = (x[len(x)//2:])
```

I know it has to go after the

```
x.append(number)
```

but  I can't get it to work using for or while loops.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451688/guessing-game-python-binary-search

Answer (score 1):

The entire `for` loop is kind of pointless, with the `x.append` line especially so. `range()` gives you a list anyway (in Python 3 it gives you a range object which can be converted to a list using the `list` function).

You could replace that with:

```
x=list(range(lowest, highest))
```

Also, this is more convention than anything technically incorrect, but in Python I think camel case is generally reserved for class names; for this reason, I would rename `middleIndex` to `middle_index`.

And finally, you don't have anything for the case when the computer guesses the right number!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is basically an interactive [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) that runs over a range of numbers. You don't actually need to use `range` or a `list`, because  you can calculate the average of your `min` and `max` values instead of finding the `middle_index`.

Here is an example implementation:

```
def main():
    print("What range will your guessed number fall within?")
    min = int(input("Min: "))
    max = int(input("Max: "))

    print("Ok; think of a number between {0} and {1}.".format(min, max))

    while min <= max:
        mid = (min + max) // 2
        if input("Is it {0}? (Y/N) ".format(mid)) == "Y":
            print("It is!? Well, that was fun.")
            return
        elif input("Darn. Is it higher than {0}? (Y/N) ".format(mid)) == "Y":
            min = mid + 1
        else:
            max = mid - 1

    print("Well, it looks like you were dishonest somewhere along the line.")
    print("I've exhausted every possibility!")

main()
```